# Undefined property: stdClass::$ELEMENT in C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium-test\phpwebdriver\WebEleent.php on line 2m8

Tags: java, php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am selenium user. I am facing  following error:

```
undefined property: stdClass::$ELEMENT in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium-test\phpwebdriver\WebElement.php on line 28
```

Workd Status. PHP  Complete setup is done. When I run sample project
it run open firefox browser and and open google.com after that firefox closed. Doesn't search key word.

Following is my code.

```
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");                            
$webdriver->get("http://www.google.com/");
$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");
if ($element) {
    $element->sendKeys(array("php webdriver" ) );
    $element->submit();
}

$webdriver->close();
```

Comment: What is output in console? Any errors?

Comment: What version of WebDriver and Firefox? Does it work with Chromedriver?

Comment: @AftabAnxari Update the question with the error trace logs